# How change language in Element UI and Vue dynamically?

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I have el-table which was rendered. User change language i have event where i want set new language. But table did not change this language dynamically, because was rendered early.
For translation we use vue-gettext

```
import elementLangDe from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/de';
import elementLocale from 'element-ui/lib/locale';
elementLocale.use(elementLangDe);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine `vue-i18n`.

```js
Vue.use(Element, {
  i18n: (key, value) => i18n.t(key, value)
})
```

Then you only need to change the value of `i18n.locale`.

Detail see:

- [main.js](https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/blob/a284c1f00738ecfa93c5550a8f87fb6925cc1c0e/src/main.js#L26)
- [index.vue](https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/blob/a284c1f007/src/components/LangSelect/index.vue#L23)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter's name which passed to `Vue.use(ElementUI, {locale})` function always is "locale".

I checked window.local that is set before to set locale variable is language that I want to set dynamic.

This is my code:

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
import locale_vi from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/vi';
import locale_ja from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/ja';
import locale_ja from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/ja';
import locale_en from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

let locale;

switch(window.local) {
  case "vi":
    locale = locale_vi;
    break;
  case "en":
    locale = locale_en;
    break;
  default:
    locale = locale_ja;
}
Vue.use(ElementUI, {locale});
```